# Curl with digest auth

Tags: node.js, node-libcurl

I have one endpoint, I have been testing with comand ubuntu, the endpoint require username and password, I run this:

```
curl --digest -u username:pass --location --request POST 'http://url' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

so I just want run in node js usign [node-libcurl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-libcurl), so I don't found the correct way to add digest authorization(username:pass), this code:

```
const { curly } = require('node-libcurl')

exports.test = async () => {

var user = 'user';
var pass = '45213';

var auth = new Buffer.alloc(user + ':' + pass).toString('base64');

const { data } = await curly.post('http://url', {
    postFields: JSON.stringify({ field: 'value' }),
    httpHeader: [
      'Content-Type: application/json',
      'Accept: application/json',
      `Authorization: Basic  + ${auth}`
    ],
})
      
      console.log(data);
};
```

using the node-libcurl library, is there a way to add authentication validation??... using username and password

I'm receiving this error:

`TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "size" argument must be of type number.`

Comment: Can you share url? I would to try my self for reproducing your problem.

Comment: Perhaps you can pass it in the URL? `http://user:45213@host:port/path`?

Comment: I get ```statusString:Unauthorized```

Comment: try with https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this code

```
const auth = new Buffer.alloc((user + ':' + pass).length).toString('base64');
```

Comment: This would be: `const auth = new Buffer.alloc(10).toString('base64');`

Comment: `ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE` error is gone correct?

Comment: I need digest authorization, basic authirization don't work, It's possible?

Comment: @jhonestrada, I need to test a real 'host:port' URL, the local URL is not reproducible to get digest auth. What is that?

Comment: I'll write you..

Comment: I got your e-mail, I will try it

Comment: @jhonestrada, I try it but I can't find the `digest` option method in Javascript. Sorry about that, the test result I send via e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

The header constructed looks incorrect to me:

`` `Authorization: Basic  + ${auth}` ``

Should it be instead:

`` `Authorization: Basic ${auth}` ``

Maybe a mistake in re-facturing..?

Comment: `Authorization: Basic ${auth}`   using back tick (`) not single quote (') and yes no plus(+)

Comment: I need digest authorization, basic authirization don't work

Comment: It's possible?..